# Tabel to css horizontal nav-bar

Tags: css, navbar

I have a horizontal menu/navigation bar that is currently laid out using a two row table.  It works fine as is, but I would like to know how to create it without using the table, if possible.  I have spent the better part of several days trying all sorts of divs/spans/uls floats block/inline etc, to no avail.  The primary constraints are:

> IE7+, FF3+
> The new solution must remain visually & functionally unchanged (to the user).
> Menu items are not all the same width, and may change.
> The row heights are 26px, to accomodate a background image, which provide a "button" look.

Here is a working example using a table: [Horizontal menu bar](http://www.santanracing.com/_/nav-test/)

So, any suggestions? (or complete solutions:)  Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
<title>Nav Bar Test</title>

<style>
body { font-family: arial; }

.page-wrapper {
   width: 850px; margin: auto; border: solid  02px  black; background: cyan;}

table.menu_bar {
   width    : 100%;
   font-size: .9em;
   border-style   : none;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }

table.menu_bar td {
   background-color: white;
   border-width    : 1px;
   padding         : 0px;
   border-style    : solid;
   border-color    : #555;
   }

.menu_bar a {
   display          : block;
   height           : 26px;
   color            : black;
   text-align       : center;
   text-decoration  : none;
   background       : url(GRAY_bg1.PNG);
   background-repeat: repeat;
   background-color : silver;
   overflow         : hidden;
   }

.menu_bar a:hover {
   background: url(RED_bg1.PNG); background-color : red;}

.menu_bar a:active {
   background: url(RED_bg2.PNG); background-color : #F55;}

.menu_bar div { margin-top: 4px; }
</style>

</head>

<body><div class="page-wrapper"><br>

<table class="menu_bar" ><tr>
   <td><a href="#" class="menu_bar"><div>Menu Item</div></a></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="menu_bar"><div>Very Long Menu Item</div></a></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="menu_bar"><div>Long Menu Item</div></a></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="menu_bar"><div>Item </div></a></td>
   <td><a href="#" class="menu_bar"><div>Menu Item</div></a></td>
</tr></table>

<br></div><!--End page-wrapper--></body></html>
```

Comment: this is not a v'll "transform and give you the code" site!!

Answer (score 0):

If it wasn't for IE7 you could use `display: table/table-row/table-cell` to make any element act as a table. Unfortunately without display: table it's very hard to accomplish what you're after without actually using a table.

I actually wrote a plugin ages ago that makes a floated list of elements take up the full width of their parent: http://exscale.se/archives/2007/11/09/jquery-full-width-navigation-plugin/ It's very limited though and may not work with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was assuming that I was missing something obvious, and I'd get lots of "duh - just do this" type of responses.  However, the more thought I give it, the more it seems that using a table is the most appropriate solution for this type of menu bar.  After all, a list is just a simple table.  <br> And, the most important point in my case is: if it ain't broke, don't fix it!